# IIS 7.5 configuring website to support http , net.pipe to invoke WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, silverlight-4.0

In IIS 7.5 i configured my asp.net website for "`http,net.pipe`" in "Enable protocols".

Note:
net.pipe configuration is done to call another module within the website (SOA).

Every thing worked fine with simple asp.net & net.pipe service invocation calling other module. But When i try to call `RIA service from silverlight 4` i get the following error

```
The provided URI scheme 'net.pipe' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: context.ListenUriBaseAddress
```

How can i configure my website to work in http & net.pipe configuration ?

Comment: PLEASE CHECK YOUR SL code, are you using httpbinding in SL? could you show us your proxy generation code of SL, so we can find the solution of your problem in a better way.

Comment: SL uses custom binary binding. If i disable net.pipe in IIS , silverlight RIA service is working fine. But with http & net.pipe enabled  it is not working.

Comment: My problem is same as  this one      http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-SE/wcf/thread/cdff7a49-ebe3-4732-aaa4-50dd32670caf

Comment: Solution is here in this link http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/208892/495194.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with new REST wcf API. Had to Filter  net.pipe, in custom Service host factory, here is the code

```
public class FilteredServiceHostFactory : HttpServiceHostFactory
{
    private static readonly List<string> _allowedSchemes;
    static FilteredServiceHostFactory()
    {
        _allowedSchemes = new List<string> {Uri.UriSchemeHttp, Uri.UriSchemeHttps};
    }
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        baseAddresses = baseAddresses.Where(uri => _allowedSchemes.Contains(uri.Scheme)).ToArray();
        return base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }
}
```